# how to add Product Name in quick view magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quickview

> Actually i am trying to show product name in quick view but here
>   product name is not coming i added the code below for product name
>   purpose here please check

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                    <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
```

> script_quickview_catalog_product_view.xml

```
  <!--BEGIN quickview MEDIA-->
  <container name="quickview_media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="quickview-media product media" before="quickview_tabs_area">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="Script_QuickView::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
  </container>
  <!--END quickview MEDIA-->

  <!--BEGIN quickview MAIN-->
  <container name="quickview_tabs_area" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="quickview-tabs" htmlId="quickview-tabs">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="quickview_tabs" template="Script_QuickView::quickview.tabs.phtml" before="-" >
      <!--MAIN-->
      <block name="product.info.main" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Script_QuickView::quickview.content.phtml" group="quickview_tabs">
        <!-- <arguments>
          <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Main</argument>
          <argument name="html_id" xsi:type="string">quickview-info-main</argument>
          <argument name="html_class" xsi:type="string">product-info-main</argument>
        </arguments> -->

        <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
         <!--Product Name Purpose-->
            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                    <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" before="product.info.sku">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
              <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
              <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
          <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
            <container name="product.info.type" before="-" />
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Script_QuickView::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
              <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
              </arguments>
            </block>
          </container>
        </container>

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
          <arguments>
            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
          </arguments>
        </block>

        <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
          <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
          </container>
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
              </block>
              <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
            </block>
          </block>
        </block>

        <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
          <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">

          </container>
        </container>

        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
          <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
          </arguments>
        </block>
      </block>
      <!--END MAIN-->
      <!-- DETAIL -->
      <block name="product.info.detail" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Script_QuickView::quickview.content.phtml" group="quickview_tabs" after="-">
        <arguments>
          <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Info</argument>
          <argument name="html_id" xsi:type="string">quickview-info-detail</argument>
          <argument name="html_class" xsi:type="string">product-info-detail</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Script_QuickView::product/view/details.phtml" >
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
              <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
              <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
              <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
              <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>

          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </block>
      </block>
      <!--END DETAIL-->
      <!--REVIEWS-->
    <!--   <block name="product.reviews" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Script_QuickView::quickview.content.phtml" group="quickview_tabs" after="-">
        <arguments>
          <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Reviews</argument>
          <argument name="html_id" xsi:type="string">reviews</argument>
          <argument name="html_class" xsi:type="string">reviews</argument>
        </arguments>
        <referenceBlock name="require-cookie">
          <arguments>
            <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="submitReviewButton" xsi:type="string">.review .action.submit</item>
            </argument>
          </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
          <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
            <arguments>
              <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
                  </item>
                </item>
              </argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </block>
      </block> -->
      <!--END REVIEWS-->
    </block>
  </container>
</container>

<referenceContainer name="quickview_area">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
  <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
      </argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>

  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_button" after="-" template="Script_QuickView::product/view/button.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
</referenceBlock>

<referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
  <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.video" after="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">
  <block class="Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Qtyincrements" name="product.info.extrahint.qtyincrements" template="qtyincrements.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="quickview_modal" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your xml after  `<container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container"....` tag

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.name" template="Script_QuickView::product/view/name.phtml" before="-" />
```

Now add one name.phtml with below content in your module folder in above path and clear cache.

```
<div class="productNamePopup"><?php echo $this->getProduct()->getName(); ?></div>
```